# What are same general properties of having f(x,x) for joint density f(x,y)?

Tags: probability, statistics, density-function

For two random variables X, Y with joint density f(x,y). What are the properties of f(x,x) and can we bound $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x,x) dx \quad and \quad \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\partial f(x,x)}{\partial y} dx?$$
And can we normalise the f(x,x) to be a density function?

Comment: Well, $\frac{\partial f(x,x)}{\partial y}=0$.  Not much else can be said.

Comment: Why should $$ \frac{\partial f(x,x)}{\partial y} = \left .\frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial y}\right|_{y=x} =0?$$

Comment: Because $f(x,x)$ is relatively constant w.r.t. $y$.  Also, $\frac{\partial f(x,x)}{\partial y}\neq \left.\frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial y}\right\vert_{y=x}$.  They are totally different.